# Which server to choose

Tags: mysql, hosting, dedicated

I currently run a centos 6 server on media temple which is great for my needs but I have had some issues installing ffmpeg and various packages. Some of the yum installs are really old. Below is a list of the other packages available.

```
Ubuntu 12.04 - LTS Precise
Ubuntu 12.10 - Quantal
Ubuntu 10.04 - LTS Lucid
Ubuntu 13.04 - Raring
Fedora 18
Debian 7.0 - Wheezy
Debian 6.0 - Squeeze
CentOS 6
```

What are the advantages of the above? how different are they really? I am looking to build a website that will do a lot of video and audio manipulation server side.

Is there one that deals with this better than the other? Do not get me wrong. My Centos server has been great. Just trying to decide whether to stick with centos for my new hosting, or whether there is a advantage for me to use another one from the above list.

Comment: ServerFault question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Ubuntu 12.10 on your local and see how it handles the packages you need. I find it much better when it comes to package management, dependency resolving, package compatibility ect.